# How to make my function generic and work with all tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I create a function GetImage() , this function is searching by id for image bytes in database and return it as array . Note that (_photo) is  a table .
my question is .. how to make this function generic and did not depend on 1 table only.
I want when i call this function I want to send the table to this function and select the image bytes then return the bytes array.

```
    public FileContentResult GetImage(Guid id)
    {
        if (id == Guid.Empty || id == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var Img = _photos.Entity.GetById(id);
        if (Img != null)
        {
            byte[] image = Img.DataFile;
            return File(image, "image/jpg");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of `_photos` here?

Comment: I use a design pattern , and i inject all tables i needed in my controller like this ==>     private readonly IUnitOfWork<Photos> _photos;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork<Photographers> _photographers;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork<Company> _company;

        public PhotosController(IUnitOfWork<Photos> photos,
                               IUnitOfWork<Photographers> photographers,
                               IUnitOfWork<Company> company)
        {
            _photos = photos;
            _photographers = photographers;
            _company = company;
        }

Comment: Do all the tables you want to use refer to all tables that contain Image?

Answer (score 0):

you probably mean similar to this

```
public FileContentResult GetImage<T>(Guid id, T table) where T : class, (your table's base class name or interface name here)
{
    if (id == Guid.Empty || id == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var Img = table.Entity.GetById(id);
    if (Img != null)
    {
        byte[] image = Img.DataFile;
        return File(image, "image/jpg");
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should i put this function please ? In generic repository class or where ?

Comment: where you put the original function.

Comment: if you use that IUnitWork as i see above, function header may be better as `public FileContentResult GetImage<T>(Guid id, T table) where T : IUnitOfWork<T>`